# google cloud print alternatives

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, printing

The original X problem is - `window.print()` is not supported on Android mobile devices.

Looking for the alternatives [Google cloud print](https://www.google.com/cloudprint/learn/) was the option however, the

```
setPrintDocument("url", "[document title]", "[document URL]")
```

method expects a document URL not the document itself.If the document is passed as is, the CSS won't render.

Any alternatives for this scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using BLOB url. Example "blob:https://crap.crap". I am not sure whether this will work or not.